# React Material Component refuse to be horizontally center here in Code Sandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, components, center

I'm trying to get my Material design to work here in the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aspnetcorereactredux-bdhjf?file=/src/components/Logger.jsx).

My problem is that I try to make it center horizontally.

Now it looks like this:

[image]

I made the top `Container` have color like `backgroundColor: "#cfe8ac"` (light green) to make it easier to see where it is. As you see it refuses to be center I have tried like `alignItems="center" justify="center"` but no luck I don't understand where to set the style

**update**

It's fixed now Thanks to @yun_jay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not caused by Material-Ui but by reactstrap.
You have to use the offset of the column in order to center the columns.

To achieve this you have to add the following to your columns in your Layout component: `xs={{ size: 6, offset: 3 }}`.
Your code would then look like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import "../../node_modules/primereact/resources/primereact.css";
import "../../node_modules/primereact/resources/themes/nova-dark/theme.css";
import NavMenu from "./NavMenu";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

export default (props) => (
  <div>
    <NavMenu />
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={{ size: 6, offset: 3 }}>{props.children[0]}</Col>
        <Col xs={{ size: 6, offset: 3 }}>{props.children[1]}</Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={{ size: 6, offset: 3 }}>{props.children[2]}</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  </div>
);
```

For further information see the documentation: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/layout/

## Live Demo

[image: Edit AspNetCoreReactRedux (forked)]

Comment: Thanks, is it ok to mix Material-UI och reactstrap as I do, I have copy past a bit, I mean is a bad custom to do? I see I also have bootstrap css loaded in index.js

Comment: I wouldn't call it bad but it definitely makes your code more complicated since you are using two different grids. That's why I would recommend you to focus on one of them, because you can achieve the same thing with both.

Comment: What does `xs={{ size: 6, offset: 3 }}` do, I cant find explanation for this, I know how this works `lg={6} sm={6} xl={6} xs={12} ` but the `size: 6` is that the same as `xs={6}`

Comment: Yes the size property is the same as `xs={6}`. The `offset: 3` will add on the right and on the left 3 empty grid spaces. For example if you want to make your column bigger you could set your size to 8. this would mean that you have to set your offset to 2 if you want the column to be centered again. This is because a 12 grid system is used and always 12 slots make up a column.

Comment: @yun_jay, AMAZING i JUST LEARN THE GRID SYSTEM. but why dont xs={8} center it, is not the `reactstrap` `col` center by default?

Comment: @Erik If you set your size to 8 only, then the grid expects another element(s) with size 4 to come after. Therefore you have to tell it that no more elements will come and the grid should rather fill the side with empty space in order to center it. This is what the offset will handle